# Error while opening parquet files using parquet-tools

Tags: command-line, parquet

I am trying to read a parquet file on my mac using parquet-tools.

This is the command i am using-

```
parquet-tools head -n 2 test.snappy.parquet
```

I am getting the following error-

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil (file:/usr/local/Cellar/parquet-tools/1.10.0/libexec/parquet-tools-1.10.0.jar) to method sun.security.krb5.Config.getInstance()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Not sure what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just a warning, not an error. It's a new restriction added with the module system in Java 9+. I see the same thing when I use parquet-tools. You can safely ignore it!